# pip install pymssql from inside docker container

Tags: docker, centos, installation, pip

My docker container is using centos6.6. It fails to pip install pymssql:

```
Step 15 : RUN pip install pymssql
 ---> Running in c6a17c43790d
Collecting pymssql
  Downloading http://piprepo-au/piprepo/pymssql/pymssql-2.1.1.zip (2.3MB)
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql: started
    Running setup.py install for pymssql: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6Tr3gO/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-DZY29I-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', '')
setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS', '6.6', 'Final')
setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.3')
setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
running install
running build
running build_ext
cythoning _mssql.pyx to _mssql.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            return uuid.UUID(bytes_le=(<char *>data)[:length])

        else:
            return (<char *>data)[:length]

    cdef int convert_python_value(self, object value, BYTE **dbValue,
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

_mssql.pyx:821:9: Signature not compatible with previous declaration

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef object msghandler

    cpdef cancel(self)
    cdef void clear_metadata(self)
    cdef object convert_db_value(self, BYTE *, int, int)
    cdef int convert_python_value(self, object value, BYTE **, int*, int*) except -1
```

Has anyone got any ideas? I have tried quite alot of things.
I didnt have this problem on ubuntu16.

.
.
.

Comment: Ill double check the kernel version but I would be very surprised if it wasn't 3.10+

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but do you want me to check kernel version inside the docker container?

Comment: Sorry - to clarify, check the specs on the Docker host just to make sure the storage driver and other systems are compatible with your build. The kernel version is going to be the same inside and out -- because it _is_ the same :)

Comment: I am running ubuntu 16 on the outside host. I can install this package on the on this os. Its in my docker container it fails

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is caused by an interface change somewhere between versions `2.1.1` and `2.1.3` of `pymssql`. I didn't have time to investigate the exact reason but after noticing the problem persisted on a `centos 7.x` docker image I was able to resolve this problem by installing a newer version of `pymssql`:

```
pip install pymssql==2.1.3
```